# Shared Element Transition with Android DataBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding, shared-element-transition, conductor

I am using Conductor API together with Android DataBinding and have been trying to make a simple shared element transition from a controller view to another controller view but it is not working.

Tapping on "Android Databinding" demo from the list of demoS will bring you to a screen where tapping on the displayed textView should transition it to the next screen.

But for now it is being faded in.

Here is [my fork](https://github.com/The0ldM0nk/Conductor/tree/integration-android-databinding) of things & here is a [ticket](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor/issues/290) for the same.

**Update:** I think something is not right in my [BindedBaseController](https://github.com/The0ldM0nk/Conductor/blob/b2a5011cbd5570dc1acf38e84f60b0f1f55216cf/demo/src/main/java/com/bluelinelabs/conductor/demo/controllers/base/BindedBaseController.java) class?

```
public abstract class BindedBaseController extends Controller {

    private ViewDataBinding mViewDataBinding;

    protected BindedBaseController() {
    }

    protected BindedBaseController(Bundle args) {
        super(args);
    }

    protected abstract View inflateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @NonNull ViewGroup container);

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @NonNull ViewGroup container) {
        View view = inflateView(inflater, container);
        mViewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view);
        onViewBound(view);
        return view;
    }

    protected void onViewBound(@NonNull View view) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroyView(@NonNull View view) {
        super.onDestroyView(view);
        mViewDataBinding.unbind();
        mViewDataBinding = null;
    }

    public ViewDataBinding getViewBinding() {
        return mViewDataBinding;
    }
}
```